# Generate random number (SQL Server)

Tags: sql-server, vba, excel

I am inserting the first letter and last letter of Username + 2 random digits to generate a receipt number. I am using VBA to do this via ADODB SQL Server connection.

i.e. for John Doe, will look something like this: JE43

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[TEP_ReceiptID] ([ReceiptID]) Values (UCase(Left(Application.username, 1) & Right(Application.username, 1)) & cast(rand()*99 as int)))
```

Issue is I am running into issues with this logic (this error):

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'JE' to data type
>   int.

Help?

**EDIT**

I tried this:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[TEP_ReceiptID] ([ReceiptID]) Values (Cast(UCase(Left(Application.username, 1) & Right(Application.username, 1)) & cast(rand()*99 as int))) as nvarchar)
```

But this does not solve the problem.

Comment: What about the error don't you understand? [Data Type Precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: Please check my edit.

Comment: You're still trying to concatenate an `int` and a `(n)varchar` there. `'string' + 1` will generate an error, `'string'` is not an `int` (have a look at the link). Your numerical value needs to be a `varchar`.

Comment: (`CAST`/`CONVERT` your random number, not the whole thing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are casting later (after concatenating a 'string' with 'int'), try the following:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[TEP_ReceiptID] ([ReceiptID]) Values (UCase(Left(username, 1) & Right(username, 1)) & cast(cast(rand()*99 as int) as nvarchar))
```

Comment: @OdaySalim, be aware that the corrected method will generate an random number but there is no guarantee it is unique.

Answer (score 0):

i'm not into VBA anymore but i think you are having some trouble with parenthesis (in the edit code), try this:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[TEP_ReceiptID] ([ReceiptID]) Values (UCase(Left(Application.username, 1) & Right(Application.username, 1)) & cast(cast(rand()*99 as int) as varchar(2)))
```